# Datatable select row count c# WFA

Tags: c#, sql, count, distinct

Help me to get the amount of each data on rows

I try use a query

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
```

like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPHvo.png)

and I try to distinct and add column like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amw59.png).

This is the code:

```
clsAccess db = new clsAccess(PATH);

string query = "";
query = "SELECT DISTINCT KODE, JUDUL FROM VW_PEMINJAMAN ORDER BY JUDUL ASC";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = db.GetSummaryData(query);

dt.Columns.Add("JUMLAH", typeof(int));
dt.Columns["JUMLAH"].SetOrdinal(2);

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string judul = dt.Rows[i]["KODE"].ToString();

    dt.Rows[i]["JUMLAH"] = 0;
}

grdAsosiasi.DataSource = dt;
grdAsosiasi.AutoSizeCols();
db.CloseDatabaseConnection();here
```

How can I get the count in every row in JUMLAH column?

```
SELECT COUNT(KODE) AS [KODE_BUKU] 
FROM VW_PEMINJAMAN;
```

and I get every row

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) 
{
    string abc = dt.rows[0]["KODE_BUKU"].ToString();
}
```

but just 1 row is showing... how can I get all rows count in datatable?

Comment: Not sure I understand. All your example rows are unique anyway so adding DISTINCT won't change the results. And a SQL COUNT simply counts up how many rows are returned by the query, and gives you that single total instead of the actual data. Perhaps you didn't know how COUNT works - check any tutorial or documentation for examples and explanations. If you show us an _example_ of exactly what result you want from your code, perhaps we can understand what you need to do, without having any more misunderstandings about the terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to get a count of every Kode based on your screenshot. Change your SQL to use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT KODE, JUDUL, COUNT(KODE) AS  JUMLAH 
FROM VW_PEMINJAMAN 
GROUP BY KODE, JUDUL
ORDER BY JUDUL ASC
```

Comment: Hehehhe thaks Cam Bruce... :D